# At the time when market opens what is the best way to know if market will go up or it will go down

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, etf, day-trading, leveraged-etf

I know markets are driven by multiple factors and any news, any time can cause market to go up and down. **Assuming there is no major event/news during the day**, at the time when market opens, what is the best way to determine if market will go up or down today.

I am tracking certain ETF and if I need to day trade, this information will be very handy.
I am new to trading and may be this is a naive questions but this will help me learn.

Comment: invent a time machine perhaps.

Comment: I strongly recommend you avoid getting into day trading based on a question like this... you can lose a lot of money quickly. Long-term investing in simple diversified low-fee funds does not have anywhere near the level of risk of daytrading, especially when you are this new.

Comment: Even just the phrase "if I **need** to day trade" makes me nervous when I read it.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon: What you said makes sense. I entered market when it was all time high (around Dec 21) and then market fell. I have had some success using day trading. I can be wrong but I believe if one does not get greedy and follow rules, one can make money day trading as well.

Comment: If any of us knew the answer to your question, do you think that it would be to our benefit to let more people in on such a wonderful money-making secret?  The reality is that no one knows how to predict the market with accuracy.

Comment: @BobBaerker: I understand and completely agree with you. No one can guess with 100% accuracy. My point is can we guess with 60-80% percent accuracy? I have seen these patterns when market is down for 3-4 days it will go up on fifth day (again nothing is set in stone and this just a pattern). You know there is there a bad news and market will go down for sure. I guess I am looking for a site that publishes accurate news and do not entice retail investors towards some sort of bias.

Comment: "I have seen these patterns when market is down for 3-4 days it will go up on fifth day" Have you checked to make sure there aren't weeks where this *isn't* true? Humans are primed to see patterns, even when they're not actually there or aren't predictable.

Comment: People can't even guess with 60-80% accuracy.  What I will offer is that if you combine risk management with market selection, you can make decent money with only a modest favorable selection ratio.  As for your pattern, I bet that there are just as many 5 day patterns like yours where when the market is down for 3-4 days it will go DOWN on the fifth day.  If I still had the software, I'd screen a database and demonstrate this.

Comment: FWIW, Tom DeMark has some indicators that involve multiple successive moves in one direction that are interesting.  What I would offer is that if an underlying is down for 10 consecutive days, while it may not be predictive, you are more likely to be near a bottom than a top :->)

Answer (score 5):

A non snarky answer to this is to act on *material non-public information*, otherwise known as *insider trading*, which is illegal and hard to come across if you're not in a position to regularly receive it. Otherwise, your guess is as good as mine when it comes to saying the market will go up or down. There are no statistically significant alpha strategies employable by individual traders, but you will often find people who tell you they have one. Most common is the use of [technical analysis](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/technicalanalysis.asp), which seeks to predict movements based purely on historical information i.e chart patterns and such. I and most financial literature believe in TA as much as Astrology (which is to say very little), and the two have interesting intersections, as seen in books like [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118369394).

Knowing what the market will do creates *Arbitrage* opportunities, which by definition will be exploited until they no longer exist, if they did exist at all. Believing that you as an individual can beat the market consistently over time is a very dangerous stance to take.

Comment: While I'm no fan of technical analysis nor do I think that market timing via astrology makes any sense, it's worth noting that Arch Crawford has had some stellar years of performance utilizing the latter. After accurately predicting the 1987 crash, Mark Hulbert starting tracking him (Hulbert tracked the performance of major newsletters and advisory services).

Comment: Since I don't keep up with this stuff, I don't know if Crawford has had any terrible years.  Here's an article noting [such performance](http://www.crawfordperspectives.com/documents/HulbertinForbes_001.pdf).  In addition, Crawford achieved best performance in several 2 year periods as well as Market Timer of the year several times.  It kinda makes you wonder if there is some substance to this :->)

Answer (score 2):

At the beginning of the day, begin waiting. Wait until the end of the day, and compare the price of the ETF then to the price at the beginning of the day. If it is higher, the market will go up that day (and already has - look, it was correct!); if it is lower, the market will go down (and already has - correct again!).

Comment: This is factually wrong and bad advice.

Comment: @ApplePie It's not real advice, but how is it factually wrong?

Comment: With all due respect I thought this was sarcasm. ` begin waiting. Wait until the end of the day,`. i don't know how this is helpful :)

Comment: @OpenStack It might be helpful to help the asker know that you cannot tell whether the market will go up or down.